# Can you pull an API Key from a google map search?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

Im New To coding and I'm trying to import google map search data (phone number, Address, company name) into a google doc.

I have tried using this code below but need to get a google map API Key to make it work and replace "Your_API_KEY_HERE" but dont know how to find it, from a search.

```
function getPhoneNumbers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var searchQuery = data[i][0];
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=" + searchQuery + "&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(json);
    
    if (dataObject.candidates.length > 0) {
      var phoneNumber = dataObject.candidates[0].formatted_phone_number;
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(phoneNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

Used this code but I don't have the google map api key so cant import any data

```
function getPhoneNumbers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var searchQuery = data[i][0];
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=" + searchQuery + "&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_phone_number&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(json);
    
    if (dataObject.candidates.length > 0) {
      var phoneNumber = dataObject.candidates[0].formatted_phone_number;
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(phoneNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't get it from a search. It's something you get from your Google developer account.

Comment: googling a simple term such as "google maps api key" would result you in some links such as [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spm/7.0.4?topic=triage-generating-api-key-google-maps) and [this](https://yoast.com/help/generate-set-google-maps-api-key/)